# How to display aspx page inside a Panel/View?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

So I have my main page with buttons on top of it. 
Below there's a MultiView (also tried with a Panel) and I want to display a different page (aspx) inside it when a user clicks the button on top of the page.

I've been trying to do this for 2 hours now and can't get this to work... No good info @ Google. 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) instead of pages. I am not aware of any case where I ever needed this functionality.

Beside that, I'm rather sure that it is not supported to insert pages into other pages.